# Reaching an object property from another property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm using an object structure for my js file and want to be able to assign one of the properties (which is an array) to one of the other properties:

```
AvGen = {

    theBody: {
        bodies: [
            fooObj,
            foo2Obj,   // <--- assign this property...
            foo3Obj
        ],
        bodyColor: '#DB6EDB',
        currBodyNr: 1,
        currBodyObj: AvGen.theBody.bodies[1]    // <--- ...to this property

// ... rest of the code
```

However, when trying to do it I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AvGen is not defined
```

If I remove 'AvGen' it says that 'theBody' isn't defined instead. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: x= foo2Obj, then currBodyObj: x, ...

Answer (score 1):

In newer browsers you could use a getter:

```
AvGen = {

    theBody: {
        bodies: [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        bodyColor: '#DB6EDB',
        currBodyNr: 1,
        get currBodyObj() {
           return AvGen.theBody.bodies[AvGen.theBody.currBodyNr];
        }
    }
}

console.log(AvGen.theBody.currBodyObj); //2
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Wck/3/)**

But you could also just use a method instead of a property:

```
currBodyNr: 1,
currBodyObj: function() {
   return AvGen.theBody.bodies[AvGen.theBody.currBodyNr];
}

//...

console.log(AvGen.theBody.currBodyObj()); //2
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to initialize the object `AvGen` first so that it takes the set values of `bodies` and then, through a function assign the one you want to `this.currBodyObj`.

Answer (score 0):

`Avgen` isn't instantiated yet on that line. Instead, do this:

```
AvGen = {};
AvGen.theBody = {};
AvGen.theBody.bodies = [fooObj, foo2Obj, foo3Obj];
AvGen.theBody.bodyColor = '#DB6EDB';
AvGen.theBody.currBodyNr = 1;
AvGen.theBody.currBodyObj = AvGen.theBody.bodies[1];
// etc..
```